# Why is it that JQuery and the Javascript DOM methods strip whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to write a chatroom in Javascript. It seems as if you send `h  e  l  l  o` in the message submission box, it places `h e l l o` in the message log on everybody's message log. I have also tried to use the native DOM methods, and the same thing happens there too.

The Javascript to place the message in the log is like this:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li style="background: #ffffff;">' + msg + '</li>'))
})
```

The HTML of where it would be placed is like this:

```
<ul id="messages">
</ul>
```

Can somebody please tell me why this happens, and how I could keep this from happening.

Comment: The whitespaces are not turned from 2 to 1, it's only the way your browser displays them. In `html` you can have as many whitespaces as you would like between words/elements and the browser will ignore them.

Comment: @Dekel So, it is impossible to fix it?

Comment: @Dekel is correct. One to force all spaces to be shown is to use non breakable space characters like `&nbsp`

Comment: Use &nbsp; to give multiple white space `h&nbsp;&nbsp;e&nbsp;&nbsp;llo` in HTML

Comment: @Vijai, `&amp;` will give the `&` sign, but a non-breaking-space (which is `&nbsp;`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers don't always display breaking whitespace when showing text, you can change that with CSS

```
#messages li {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

The valid values are as follows

```
Value    |  Description
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
normal   |  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. 
         |  Text will wrap when necessary. This is default.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
nowrap   |  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. 
         |  Text will never wrap to the next line. 
         |  The text continues on the same line until a <br> tag is encountered.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
pre      |  Whitespace is preserved by the browser. 
         |  Text will only wrap on line breaks.  
         |  Acts like the <pre> tag in HTML.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
pre-line |  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace.
         |  Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
pre-wrap |  Whitespace is preserved by the browser. 
         |  Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
initial  |  Sets this property to its default value.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
inherit  |  Inherits this property from its parent element.
_________|_________________________________________________________________________
```

```js
var msg = "h  e  l  l  o";

$('#messages').append($('<li style="background: #ffffff;">' + msg + '</li>'));
$('#messages2').append($('<li style="background: #ffffff;">' + msg + '</li>'));
```

```css
#messages li {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="messages"><li>With white-space</li></ul>
<ul id="messages2"><li>Without white-space</li></ul>
```

Comment: I'll go try that.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the msg to a pre tag, that will prevent the browser from formatting the text:

```
$('#messages').append($('<li style="background: #ffffff;"><pre>' + msg + '</pre></li>'))
```